# NSEC3 resource records with RSASHA256 or only NSEC3*?

Tags: dnssec

Is it possible to use NSEC3 resource records with RSASHA256 keys or does NSEC3 require using NSEC3RSASHA1 or NSEC3DSA keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `RSASHA1` was assigned a separate identifier for use together with `NSEC3` is that `RSASHA1` had been defined and already been in use for a long time before `NSEC3` existed.
Thus, when introducing `NSEC3` it was deemed [best for compatibility](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5155#section-2) with existing deployed software to not extend how `RSASHA1` should work but to present the updated spec as an entirely new algorithm `RSASHA1-NSEC3-SHA1` which existing software would clearly recognize that it did not support instead of incorrectly using its `NSEC`-only code with `NSEC3` zones.

When later algorithms such as [`RSASHA256`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5702#section-5.2), [`ECDSAP256SHA256`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6605#section-5), etc have been introduced, these have included support for `NSEC3` from the get-go.

As you can see in the [listing of the assigned DNSSEC algorithms](https://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-sec-alg-numbers/dns-sec-alg-numbers.xhtml), there are no `NSEC3` variations for any newer algorithms.

Comment: You get to finish this first and it has everything covered. Just wanted to add that [RFC 6944](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6944) might also be interesting to read.